# How do I get full sentences to print after reading in a text file?

Tags: java, filtering, bufferedreader

I am trying to read in a technical paper, separate all the sentences, use a filter to find key terms and phrases in the sentences, and then create my own abstract.

What I have so far is two `BufferedReaders` reading a text file with a paragraph in it, and my filter being read in. Each line is then being stored into an `ArrayList` and printed to the console to test if they are being read correctly.

I want to know if I am approaching this the correct way by using a `BufferedReader` instead of a `Scanner`.  I just want to be able to print out all the sentences after a '.' (dot), a '!' (exclamation-point), or a '?' (question-mark) for right now, so I know that the file is being read correctly.

This is my code so far:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Filtering {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<String> lines1 = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> lines2 = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream("paper.txt");
            FileInputStream fstream2 = new FileInputStream("filter2.txt");  
            DataInputStream inStream1 = new  DataInputStream (fstream1);
            DataInputStream inStream2 = new DataInputStream (fstream2);

            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inStream1));
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inStream2));

            String strLine1;
            String strLine2;

            while ((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
                lines1.add(strLine1);
            }

            while ((strLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                lines2.add(strLine2);
            }

            inStream1.close();
            inStream2.close();
        }   
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        System.out.println(lines1);
        System.out.println(lines2);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you read the entire file into a single `String` (I would use a `StringBuilder` for performance reasons) then you can use `String's` `split()` function to split it into an array based on your regex and you can use that to get sentences.

Comment: ok I will give that a shot but what should the capacity be on the builder because the tech papers will vary in length and all that good stuff

Comment: Are your files really big so that they would not hold in memory?

Comment: A `StringBuilder` will grow to accommodate the all the necessary characters. However, if the paper is very long (like you'll run out of memory) you can periodically (when you reach a certain size) do a split and clear out the buffer (make sure to save any partial sentences at the end).

Comment: no memory shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 1):

- It is a good practice to use a BufferedReader to read any File as it will buffer the File instead of accessing each bytes one by one
- The DataInputStream is not needed
- You should specify a character encoding in your InputStreamReader
- You could accumulate all your string in a StringBuilder so that you have the whole text in a single reference
- You may want to look into [BreakIterator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/BreakIterator.html) to split your text into sentences. Have a look at getSentenceInstance().

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.text.BreakIterator;

public class Filtering {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File paperFile = new File("paper.txt");
        File filterFile = new File("filter2.txt");
        // If you want you could roughly initiate the stringbuilders to their
        // approximate future size
        StringBuilder paper = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder filter2 = new StringBuilder();

        FileInputStream fstream1 = null;
        FileInputStream fstream2 = null;
        try {
            fstream1 = new FileInputStream(paperFile);
            fstream2 = new FileInputStream(filterFile);

            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream1, "UTF-8"));
            BufferedReader br2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream2, "UTF-8"));

            String strLine1;
            String strLine2;

            while ((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null) {
                paper.append(strLine1).append('\n');
            }
            while ((strLine2 = br2.readLine()) != null) {
                filter2.append(strLine2).append('\n');
            }

        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            if (fstream1 != null) {
                fstream1.close();
            }
            if (fstream2 != null) {
                fstream2.close();
            }
        }
        String paperString = paper.toString();
        String filterString = filter2.toString();
        System.out.println(paperString);
        System.out.println(filterString);

        // To break it into sentences
        BreakIterator boundary = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance();
        boundary.setText(paperString);
        int start = boundary.first();
        for (int end = boundary.next(); end != BreakIterator.DONE; start = end, end = boundary.next()) {
            System.out.println(paper.substring(start, end));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by a character encoding in the InputStreamReader? also I am unfamiliar with the String Builder so what is the best way to use that?

Comment: Character encoding defines how a characters is mapped onto bytes and vice versa. Have a look at the constructors of InputStreamReader and you will see that some of them take a charset/character encoding (like UTF-8, ISO-8859-1, Cp1252, MacRoman, etc...). I will update to show how you could use a StringBuilder

Comment: thanks that helped out a a lot to understand how to use StringBuilder. I will update in a bit with progress